# Dismiss ModalView Programmatically by done button

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to click on done button to dismiss modalview programmatically. I think `UIButton` is better than `UIBarButtonItem` to add `UIControlEventsTouchupInside`.

But with `UIButton` I'm confused what buttontype should use.

```
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    

  UIBarButtonItem * button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                          target:self
                                                                          action:@selector(dismissViewaction:)] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely want to use `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` or `UIButtonTypeCustom`

With the custom type, you can add images for display.
You can try "stealing" these images from the `UIBarButtonItem` (image property defined in `UIBarItem`) and making the custom button look like the `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` button

```
UIBarButtonItem * buttonForImage = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil                                                                       action:nil] autorelease];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setImage:buttonForImage.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Things to look out for.  When setting an image for a UIButton, it does not scale to the size of the button according to `contentMode` property.  If you want the image to follow the rules of the `contentMode` property, use `setBackgroundImage: forState:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the type of button doesn't matter. You have to assign an action or a selector to the button.
Something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *bttItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(yourBttAction:)] autorelease];
```

the action:

```
- (IBAction) yourBttAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Done Button clicked");

    //do something
}
```

If the button is on the modalViewController, I usualy, for dismiss it, I use:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)];
```

or

```
//if you have a navigationController
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)];
```

But if you want to use a delegate to dismiss it, take a look at this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/3/ipad-modal-view-controllers.html)